# functions async, await in express return undefined the response

Tags: node.js, express

i have the routes and the services in diferent files
the user save successfully
but the function return is undefined

```
module.exports = async(app, passport) =>{ 
  app.post('/x/v1/user/registro', async(req, res)=>{
    const saveUser = await userServices.create(req.body)
    console.log(saveUser)
  })
})
```

and the function that save the user

```
class userServices {
    create(user, callback){ 
            var newUsuario = new User() 
            newUsuario.username =  user.username,
            newUsuario.save(callback);   
        }
}

module.exports = new userServices()
```

Comment: Well `create` doesnt return anything.. you're supposed to pass a callback to it and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to this:

```
const saveUser = await userServices.create(req.body, (elem)=>{console.log('elem',elem)})
```

Comment: thanks @alex works, but if i want save the response in the const saveUser because currently is saved in elem

Comment: @FERNANDOORTIZ you can wrap callback to promise, google it